# PHP : how to login to chatrooms by curl

Tags: php, curl

i want to play with curl functions for different examples!
for example i want to login to chatrooms by this code:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.lxchat.ir/';
    $postVars = array('username'=>'Alberto','password'=>'','gender'=>'1');
    $tmpfname = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postVars);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmpfname);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmpfname);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $run = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $info['redirect_url'];
?>
```

but this code didn't work!!! how to resolve this problem?
1- Login to chatroom
2- send a message
please help me ...
Thanks

Comment: `redirect_count` is zero. have you seen that?

Comment: I know these kind of websites. these can not be hacked into easily, you should build more complicated curl requests .... and this question is not good cause it gonna be used for suspicious goals.

Comment: thanks .. The question is not only out of curiosity. trust me ...

Comment: after you logged in as a **free** user the website may request phone number or similar from you. this is how these scripts work. you can not achieve what you want with one request (as I said). multiple requests should take place.

Comment: that's right .. the first i should be login to site then register and finally send my message ! but i don't login to site! can you do it?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to provide post data you should use http_build_query. I mean use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postVars));
```

instead of

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVars);
```

It may be your problem.

Comment: `may`s and `might`s could be part of a comment... wouldnt they? As I know they are both the same.

Comment: curl will happily accept an array and build the query string for you

Comment: @R3Z4BH there are may be a lot of different parameters for your succesful login. I have mentioned one them

Comment: thanks so much bro .. can you tell me about other problems that prevent to login successfully??  how can i solve this problem ! :( please help me to learn this :(